# lift libs in Eclipse ScalaIDE is incompatible with all scala versions

Tags: scala, sbt, lift, scala-ide

Last day i start Scala with lift framework and Eclipse IDE. after checking this link: 
http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/lift24scalaide20/
I setup my project with eclipse. the first time the lift-basic runs as well as any project. but after trying to start a new project eclipse got 12 errors to me with content like this:

> lift-actor_2.12-3.0.1.jar of lift_parsing_web build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.12.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.

hear is my **build.sbt** file:

```
name := "lift-parsing"

organization := "my.company"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies ++= {
       val liftVersion = "3.0.1"
       Seq(
               "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
               "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",
               "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26" % "test",
               "junit" % "junit" % "4.7" % "test",
               "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26",
               "org.scala-tools.testing" % "specs_2.9.1" % "1.6.9",
               "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.147"
       )
}
```

in this file i test lift 3.0.1 with scala 2.12.1 as this two version are installed.
but before this test I used the default 2.9.1 scala version and 2.4 lift version and also same problems. in some solutions i change the compiler setting and ignore this error but after that eclipse can't biuld the project and make .class file.

scala: 2.12.1
sbt: 0.13
lift: 3.0.1

finally this is my screen error. thanks for help

[errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdQcZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if Eclipse has a separate Scala version configuration beyond the one that you define in your sbt file. 2.12.0 and 2.12.1 should be binary compatible, so this shouldn't be a problem if you're using 2.12.1. Also try to build this directly using sbt and see if it registers a problem---if not, that implies it's probably an Eclipse configuration issue.